# Really tricky integration-----double U and trig substitution

Tags: integration

The definite integral $h(x) = \sin x/(1 + x^2)$ on the closed interval $[-1,1]$

$\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x$, $x = \tan \theta$

$$x = \tan \theta$$
$$dx = \sec^2 \theta \, d\theta$$

now I have to find $\sin x$ in terms  of $\theta$

I tried working through this but could not get anywhere.
I feel like there is a double $u$ substitution somewhere....

Answer (score 4):

The integral is $0$. Notice

$$ h(-x) = -h(x) $$

Hence $h$ is odd. In particular

$$ \int_{[-1,1]} h(x) = \int_{[-1,1]} \frac{ \sin x }{1 + x^2} = 0 $$

Comment: what? Im sorry I don't understand one bit. I thought we start by trig substitution.

Comment: this makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: make an effort to understand. I am sure you have learned the concept of odd and even functions and how this relates to definite integrals on intervals of the form $[-a,a]$.

Comment: Umm actually I have not.

Comment: I'm junior in high school, i have learnt odd and even functions but not as a way of solving definite integral problems.Could we not solve this by trig substitution and then double 'U' substitution?

Comment: @jjjesse The integrand does not have an elementary closed form antiderivative, so the only way you are going to be able to conclude that the definite integral is zero is if you follow Horacio's reasoning; that is to say, because $h(-x) = -h(x)$ for all $x$, then $$\int_{x=-1}^0 h(x) \, dx = - \int_{x=0}^1 h(x) \, dx,$$ consequently the integral over the total interval $[-1,1]$ must be zero.  Of course, we should also take care to note that the integrand is bounded on this interval, so that we are dealing with a **proper** definite integral.

Comment: Intuitively, the area under the curve from $-1$ to $0$ is the negative of the area from $0$ to $1$, and adding them gives 0.

Comment: I get it now, thanks :) herpup what exactly do you mean though by 'The integrand does not have an elementary closed form antiderivative' what do you mean by this layman's terms? why is this?

Comment: It means you won't be able to find the anti-derivative using the methods you've learned in basic calculus. It doesn't have a 'nice' form like $x^n$ or $\sin x$